# My data are displaying wrong in my table (html) with foreach. What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: php, mysql

it's my first time here. I hope yours can help me and we can up this! Sorry for my bad english, then...

I have 2 tables STUDENTS and GRADES. The table STUDENTS have the people that have GRADES and the GRADES have the Grade, Phase that people have...

I need to display like this

```
Matter  |  1º Phase |  2º Phase  |
Math    |  1.0      |  2.0       |
Science |  2.0      |  4.0       |
```

But I got.

```
Matter   |   1º Phase |   2º Phase   |
Math
|        1.0       |
|        2.0       |
Science
|        2.0       |
|        4.0       |
```

See my code:

```
<?php
foreach($grades->getGradesByStudentID($id) as $grade) {
    echo '<tr>';
        foreach($matters->getMattersByID($grade['matter_id']) as $matter_v) {
            echo "<td>$matter_v[name]</td>";
        }
        if($grade['phase'] == "1º bimestre") {
            echo "<td>hue</td>";
        }
        if($grade['phase'] == "2º bimestre") {
            echo "<td>$grade[grade]</td>";
        }
    echo '</tr>';
}

?>
```

Comment: post the array please..

Comment: In your echo's try using the `align` html tag

Comment: oh wait - do u want...`foreach($matters->getMattersByID($grade['matter_id']) as $matter_v) {
            echo "<td>$matter_v[name]</td>";
        
        if($grade['phase'] == "1º bimestre") {
            echo "<td>hue</td>";
        }
        if($grade['phase'] == "2º bimestre") {
            echo "<td>$grade[grade]</td>";
        }}`

Comment: the `if` statements should go inside the `for each`?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual array data, it’s hard to say what the issue is. But superficially it seems like your `if` statements should be placed within the context of the `foreach` loop. Here is my take on how this should be refactored:

```
<?php

foreach($grades->getGradesByStudentID($id) as $grade) {
    echo '<tr>';
        foreach($matters->getMattersByID($grade['matter_id']) as $matter_v) {
            echo "<td>" . $matter_v['name'] . "</td>";
            if($grade['phase'] == "1º bimestre") {
                echo "<td>" . $grade['hue'] . "</td>";
            }
            if($grade['phase'] == "2º bimestre") {
               echo "<td>" . $grade['grade'] . "</td>";
            }
        }
    echo '</tr>';
}

?>
```

In addition to placing the `if` stuff within the `foreach` loop, I also used string concatenation for the `echo "<td>" . … . "</td>";` stuff. Also, on one line you had `echo "<td>hue</td>";` but I assume that should have been `echo "<td>" . $grade['hue'] . "</td>";` so adjusted it to be that.